# storageclient class can't be found?

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying desperately to figure out how to create a simple audio transcription script (for longer audio files) via PHP (the only language I know). I'm getting the error **Class 'Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient' not found**

I'm using the gcloud console code editor and everything should be installed (unless there is a separate composer install just for cloud storage, although I haven't been able to find anything about it in the documentation if there is).

I also entered **gcloud auth application-default print-access-token** which printed out an access token, but I don't know what (if any) I'm supposed to do with that other than the "set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" command that I copied and pasted into the console shell prompt.

Here's the php code:

```
<?php
namespace Google\Cloud\Samples\Speech;
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Exception;
# [START speech_transcribe_async_gcs]
use Google\Cloud\Speech\SpeechClient;
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;
use Google\Cloud\Core\ExponentialBackoff;

$projectId = 'xxxx';
$speech = new SpeechClient([
    'projectId' => $projectId,
    'languageCode' => 'en-US',
]);

$filename = "20180925_184741_L.mp3";

# The audio file's encoding and sample rate
$options = [
    'encoding' => 'LINEAR16',
    'sampleRateHertz' => 16000,
    'languageCode' => 'en-US',
    'enableWordTimeOffsets' => false,
    'enableAutomaticPunctuation' => true,
    'model' => 'video',
];

function transcribe_async_gcs($bucketName, $objectName, $languageCode = 'en-US', $options = [])
{
    // Create the speech client
    $speech = new SpeechClient([
        'languageCode' => $languageCode,
    ]);
    // Fetch the storage object
    $storage = new StorageClient();
    $object = $storage->bucket($bucketName)->object($objectName);
    // Create the asyncronous recognize operation
    $operation = $speech->beginRecognizeOperation(
        $object,
        $options
    );
    // Wait for the operation to complete
    $backoff = new ExponentialBackoff(10);
    $backoff->execute(function () use ($operation) {
        print('Waiting for operation to complete' . PHP_EOL);
        $operation->reload();
        if (!$operation->isComplete()) {
            throw new Exception('Job has not yet completed', 500);
        }
    });
    // Print the results
    if ($operation->isComplete()) {
        $results = $operation->results();
        foreach ($results as $result) {
            $alternative = $result->alternatives()[0];
            printf('Transcript: %s' . PHP_EOL, $alternative['transcript']);
            printf('Confidence: %s' . PHP_EOL, $alternative['confidence']);
        }
    }
}
# [END speech_transcribe_async_gcs]

transcribe_async_gcs("session_audio", $filename, "en-US", $options);
```

Answer (score 0):

With apologies, PHP is not a language I'm proficient with but, I suspect you haven't (and must) install the client library for Cloud Storage so that your code may access it. This would explain its report that the Class is missing.

The PHP client library [page](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) includes two alternatives. One applies if you're using Composer, the second -- possibly what you want -- a direct download which you'll need to path correctly for your code.

Some time ago, I wrote a short blog [post](https://medium.com/google-cloud/getting-started-w-php-on-gcp-a68246f9054c) providing a simple example (using Cloud Storage) for each of Google's supported languages. Perhaps it will help you too.